# Counting multiple columns with the same criteria

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I would like to count multiple columns based on their contents. Each column I want to count(alpha,bravo and charlie) has either 'T' or 'F', I only want to count those with a 'T'.

So far i have:

```
select t1.name, count(t1.alpha), count(t1.bravo), count(t1.charlie)
from t1
  where alpha='T',
  or bravo='t'
  or charlie='t'
group by name
order by name asc;
```

However the figures i am getting dont match what I get if i run

```
select count(*)
from t1
where name='test'
and alpha='t';
```

this example would need to be run in 16 different configurations to get the results i am seeking hence it not being a practical solution to write multiple versions of it.

Comment: In this case, for example in you Alpha values - you are also counting the alpha values that donot equal to 'T' but instead have (bravo='T' or charlie='T) because of your 'OR' condition in your where clause

Comment: thanks SoulTrain I figured that was what was happening due to the discrepancy in the results i was getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `where` clause and use `Conditional Aggregate` instead, which will help you to `count` the rows only when data is `T`.

```
select t1.name, 
count(case when t1.alpha ='T' then 1 end),
count(case when t1.bravo='T' then 1 end),
count(case when t1.charlie='T' then 1 end)
from t1
group by name
order by name asc;
```